# Is it possible to create virtual UART port in linux from I2C / SPI interface data?

Tags: linux, virtual, uart, i2c, spi

I have a program which uses data from serial port and the hardware has only I2C / SPI interfaces free. The program is run on Linux. Is it possible to create a virtual I2C/SPI - UART port ? (like the virtual USB - UART port.)

Comment: Presumably by *"virtual UART port"* you are looking for a tty device that uses the termios interface.  Look in the Linux source directory **drivers/tty/serial/** and `grep` for "spi_" to find a few drivers for UARTs that are connected through SPI , e.g. **max3100.c**.